# Error with creating gitlab-runner instance

Tags: gitlab-ci, devops, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a problem, with creating gitlab-runner, when I create runner through settings of gitlab CI/CD page, I have this output in console with command `gitlab-runner register...`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj9EM.png)

I try to reinstall gitlab-runner on linux.
I think that problem of nginx or cloudflare settings.